# hex to RGB colour representation

Tags: html

Good day. I am trying to write a code that will input any file type,convert the data to hex then RBG colour representation. My assumption was that if i have a 100 KB mp3 file the conversion  to hex it will be smaller that the original 100 KB file. only to find i get 200 KB of hex. when i convert hex to RGB colour i get 373 KB of PNG. I am failing to understand because if i have 10101010 binary is = to AA hex and 6 hex makes one RGB colour, the maths tells me that the end result must be relatively smaller than the original file.

please help me correct the script to get a small output PNG file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>File Hex to RGB Color Converter</title>
  <script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    let imageData = null;

    function processFile() {
      var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
      var file = fileInput.files[0];

      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function(event) {
        var binaryContent = event.target.result;
        var hexContent = convertToHex(binaryContent);

        var resultContainer = document.getElementById('result');
        resultContainer.innerHTML = "";

        var hexValues = hexContent.match(/[0-9A-Fa-f]{6}/g) || [];

        hexValues.forEach(function(hex) {
          var hexContainer = document.createElement('div');

          if (hex.length === 6) {
            var rgb = hexToRGB(hex);
            hexContainer.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + rgb.join(",") + ")";
            hexContainer.style.width = "5px";
            hexContainer.style.height = "5px";
          }

          resultContainer.appendChild(hexContainer);
        });

        createImage();
      };

      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    }

    function convertToHex(buffer) {
      var hex = '';
      var view = new DataView(buffer);
      for (var i = 0; i < view.byteLength; i++) {
        var value = view.getUint8(i).toString(16);
        if (value.length === 1) {
          value = '0' + value; // ensure two digits
        }
        hex += value;
      }
      return hex.toUpperCase();
    }

    function hexToRGB(hex) {
      var r = parseInt(hex.substring(0, 2), 16);
      var g = parseInt(hex.substring(2, 4), 16);
      var b = parseInt(hex.substring(4, 6), 16);
      return [r, g, b];
    }

    function createImage() {
      var resultContainer = document.getElementById('result');
      html2canvas(resultContainer).then(function(canvas) {
        imageData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      });
    }

    function downloadImage() {
      if (imageData) {
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.download = "color_palette.png";
        link.href = imageData;
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
      }
    }
  </script>
  <style>
    #result {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      gap: 2px;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .hexContainer {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      border: 1px solid black;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>File Hex to RGB Color Converter</h1>
  <input type="file" id="fileInput">
  <button onclick="processFile()">Process File</button>
  <div id="result"></div>
  <button onclick="downloadImage()">Download Image</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The script works fine but i want it to produce smaller output that include all the data in the original file

Comment: You take binary data (e.g. 1bit) and convert it into string -> makes more space. `'0'` is 8 bits!

Comment: The only way you're going to make such a file smaller is with a compression algorithm - but the file is probably already heavily compressed.

Comment: That `10101010` is one byte. `AA` is two characters, which may be *4* bytes